# Append result of variable to a list

Tags: python, list, variables, python-3.x, append

I am trying to add the result of a variable `f` to the end of a list `list_name`. However, when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
list_name.append[f]
```

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list_name.append(f)
```

`append` is a method (function) so you should call it with simple parentheses.

And of course, a function is not subscriptable, so you get an error...

(An object is subscriptable when it has a [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method.)