# Appending in Python 3 issue

Tags: list, python-3.x, append

This is the part of the code that gives me a hard time:

```
if (id1 == id2):
    idlist.append[id1]
```

The error:

> builtins.TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
>   the problematic line is "idlist.append[id1]"

Any idea why ? I am trying to append the value id1 hold into idlist.

Thanks !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append result of variable to a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350401/append-result-of-variable-to-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Lists have a method that is called **append**

Because it is a method you should use it like that:

```
.append(something)
```

ie. invoke (like any other func)

Comment: I have no idea why I used squre brackets *_* Thanks for the comment Artur !